# How to make nested table span all underlying cells

Tags: tables

How can I make a nested multicolumn table span all its underlying columns such that 1 2 3 do not look squashed together but are rather distributed equally over the 2 cells?

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
  something long & here too \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}{ l c r } 1 2 3\end{tabular}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply insert `\hfill` for stretching:

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
  something long & here too \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{1 \hfill 2 \hfill 3} \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image: table]

or use it also at beginning and end, if necessary use `\hspace*{\fill}` instead:

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
  something long & here too \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\hfill 1\hfill 2\hfill 3\hspace*{\fill}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image: table]

If you really wish to nest tables, you could use `tabularx` inside with `X` columns. For this you would need to know the cell width.

Comment: And how can one know the cell width?